# PHP Imagick- 500 internal server error

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to get Imagick working; My development environment is:

- Windows 2008 Server
- II7
- PHP 5.3.10
- Imagick is installed (I hope properly)

I:

- Checked if the class exists, and it does. (`if (class_exists('Imagick')) {}`)
- Checked if I can create an Imagick obj, creates object (`new Imagick();`)
- Applied the method and that worked too! (`$image ->setResolution(72, 72);`)

But, whenever I try to work with any image I have in the folder, I get a `500 - Internal server error`.

Any one of these scripts will generate a 500 error:

```
$image = new Imagick('images/logo.jpg');
```

or

```
$image ->readImage("images/logo.jpg");
```

or anything that involves accessing an image from a folder.

Comment: Do you have PHP set to show errors?

Comment: Please show the output from your web-server error.log

Comment: yes, I have that and here is the latest error I am getting. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'must specify image size `C:/Windows/TEMP/magick-XWnp2oNn' @ error/mvg.c/ReadMVGImage/185' in d:\inetpub\...\test.php:10 Stack trace: #0 d:\inetpub\..\test.php(10): Imagick->readimageblob('

Comment: And here is the code:
$svg = file_get_contents("svg/sample.svg");
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($svg);

$image->setImageFormat("png32");

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the full path to your image when creating a new Imagick object

```
$image = new Imagick('/full/path/to/images/logo.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks, This has pushed me one step further! Now I am getting an exception: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to read the file: http://.... (FYI: the image does exist and I can see it in a browser when I used the same path and have also given my IIS user a read and write access to that folder) what am I missing?

Comment: you can't open a file from a webserver, you need to specify the full local path

Comment: you also should enable error output in your php.ini with `display_errors = On`

Comment: display_errors is on and I have posted the errors I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue happened to me on a shared hosting service.

I needed to uncheck the GD graphics library from the list of included libraries, because there was an internal conflict between GD & Imagick.